# Live encode H.264 stream on Android

Tags: android, encoding, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am writing an Android app where I plan to encode several images in to a live h.264 video stream that can be replayed on any browser. I am using the MediaCodec API for encoding and then MediaMuxer to write it to a file as per the example here http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/.

What I am stuck with is that how to tell the encoder/muxer to encode it such that it can be progressively played back. From the examples only when the encoder/muxer.stop()/encoder/muxer.release() call is made, then the video file gets the right meta headers, etc..

Thanks

Comment: you need to move the MPEG4 meta information from the end of file to the beginning see http://mithunme.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/streaming-mp4-via-http/

Comment: The `MediaMuxer` class really wants to write a .mp4 file to disk.  It's not suited to streaming.  If what you're after is live-streaming an edited video feed from your app to a host browser, you need to sort out network video streaming protocols.  But I'm not convinced I fully understand what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are considering the time at which each frame is shown.

You need to give MediaMuxer, along with the frame, the right "**MediaCodec.BufferInfo**," whose "**presentationTimeUs**" is set accordingly.

For example, there are 3 frames, each is shown for 1 second in the video:

```
sec 0---------1---------2-----------
    frame1    frame2    frame3 


int[] timestampSec = {0, 1, 2};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    muxer.writeSampleData(trackId, 
                          frame[i], 
                          timeStampSec[i] * 1000000); 
}
```

As to initialization and ending of MediaMuxer:

1. addTrack: when you get **index == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED** when you call **MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()**, send the format to MediaMuxer to initialize a new track for this format(it's "vidio/avc" in this case).
2. mediamuxer.start()
3. start put frames as above
4. mediamuxer.stop(), release()